# Ghost light following main light at point of origin

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a spotlight in my OpenGL project, the light currently shines down the -z axis like a ceiling light, towards the floor, which is just a big quad.

I currently have a cube at the origin of the light, that follows the light around, so I can see exactly where the light is at all times.

My problem is that there is another brighter spotlight that follows the main light, it starts at the origin, or the bottom left corner of the floor.

I'd like to remove this white light, as I don't know what's causing it, or how to remove it.

I have tried to play around with some of the variables and see their impact, but I've had little to no success.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

The error:

[image: The error]

```
//ceiling light
GLfloat Light_Ambient[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
GLfloat Light_Diffuse[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
GLfloat Light_Position[] = { Sun.X, Sun.Y, Sun.Z, 1.0f };
GLfloat Spot_Direction[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f };

//ambient
GLfloat Light_Ambient1[] = { 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f };
GLfloat Light_Diffuse1[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
GLfloat Light_Position1[] = { Sun.X, Sun.Y, Sun.Z, 1.0f };

//ceiling light
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, Light_Ambient);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, Light_Diffuse);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, Light_Position);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 55);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, Spot_Direction);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, 5);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

//ambient
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, Light_Ambient1);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, Light_Diffuse1);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, Light_Position1);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
```

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: oh, sorry, i'll add it now

Comment: @chbchb55 kinda hard to show a graphics related issue, without an image isn't it?

Comment: @chbchb55 so are you suggesting OP just wrote "What's my error?" without telling or showing what the problem is? Sure if it's a syntax problem, then you can add the error the compile throws at you. But as it's a graphics problem, then an image of the issue is important. Using a debugger wouldn't help you in that instance.

Comment: @chbchb55: Did you ever debug a OpenGL application? There is no debugger that would show you why a specific pixel is shaded in a specific way. Having an image that shows what happens is a very crucial thing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed some things around and I seem to have solved it.

```
//ceiling light
GLfloat Light_Ambient[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
GLfloat Light_Diffuse[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
GLfloat Light_Position[] = { Sun.X, Sun.Y, Sun.Z, 1.0f };
GLfloat Spot_Direction[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f };

//ambient
GLfloat Light_Ambient1[] = { 0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f, 1.0f };
GLfloat Light_Diffuse1[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
GLfloat Light_Position1[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0.0f };

//ceiling light
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, Light_Ambient);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, Light_Diffuse);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, Light_Position);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 55);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, Spot_Direction);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, 20);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

//ambient
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, Light_Ambient1);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, Light_Diffuse1);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, Light_Position1);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
```

**UPDATE:**

I'm returning to edit this months later simply because I feel that this answer may help a lot of people with OpenGL and this confusion with lights.

If your lights are broken (like mine were) there's actually a good chance there's nothing wrong with your lights at all, but how you're rendering the world. It's worthwhile to remember that opengl looks a little like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/65YVD.jpg

What I was actually doing wrong, as you can see from my initial question i was convinced that the Z was the Y and the Y was the Z, and vice versa, this broke all of my lighting calculations back then. If your lights look like mine do, there's a good chance that you're confusing your axis, it isn't that hard to do this when moving from 2d to 3D opengl.

Comment: I have rolled back to the previous version with the code and added your new edit in an update. As you mentioned, the code in the answer may help someone in the future. If you think the code adds no value to the answer, please rollback to the version with just the text.